# System configuration:array serialization in magento 2

Tags: system.xml, magento2.2.2, system-config

I have created system configuration for my custom module like below

**Group 1**
[image: Group1]

It works fine for a group 1 and generates a unique id for each row.

**But while adding the second group, It adds the same id for second group rows**
***In the second group It contains two rows with the same id, So It creates reflection while adding values. So please provide me a solution***

**Group 2**

[image: Group 2]

My template

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
$_htmlId = $block->getHtmlId() ? $block->getHtmlId() : '_' . uniqid();
?>
<div class="design_theme_ua_regexp" id="grid<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_htmlId ?>">
    <div class="admin__control-table-wrapper">
        <table class="admin__control-table" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getElement()->getId() ?>">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach ($block->getColumns() as $columnName => $column): ?>
                        <th><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $column['label'] ?></th>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="addRow<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_htmlId ?>"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getElement()->getName() ?>[__empty]" value="" />
    <script>
        require([
                'mage/template',
                'prototype'
        ], function (mageTemplate) {
        // create row creator
        window.arrayRow<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_htmlId ?> = {

        // define row prototypeJS template
        template: mageTemplate(
                '<tr id="<%- _id %>">'
<?php foreach ($block->getColumns() as $columnName => $column): ?>
            + '<td>'
                    + '<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderCellTemplate($columnName) ?>'
                    + '<\/td>'
<?php endforeach; ?>
        + '<\/tr>'
                ),
                add: function(rowData, insertAfterId) {
                // generater default template data
                var templateValues;
                // Prepare template values
                if (rowData) {
                templateValues = rowData;
                } else {
                var d = new Date();
                templateValues = {
<?php foreach ($block->getColumns() as $columnName => $column): ?>
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $columnName ?>: '',
                            'option_extra_attrs': {},
<?php endforeach; ?>
                _id: '_' + d.getTime() + '_' + d.getMilliseconds()
                };
                }

                // Insert new row after specified row or at the bottom
                if (insertAfterId) {
                Element.insert($(insertAfterId), {after: this.template(templateValues)});
                } else {
                Element.insert($('addRow<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_htmlId ?>'), {bottom: this.template(templateValues)});
                }

                // Fill controls with data
                if (rowData) {
                var rowInputElementNames = Object.keys(rowData.column_values);
                for (var i = 0; i < rowInputElementNames.length; i++) {
                if ($(rowInputElementNames[i])) {
                $(rowInputElementNames[i]).setValue(rowData.column_values[rowInputElementNames[i]]);
                }
                }
                }
                },
        }

        // bind add action to "Add" button in last row
<?php if (!$this->getArrayRows()): ?>
            document.observe('dom:loaded', arrayRow<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_htmlId ?>.add.bind(arrayRow<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_htmlId ?>, false, false));
<?php endif; ?>

        // add existing rows
<?php
foreach ($block->getArrayRows() as $_rowId => $_row) {
    /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "arrayRow{$_htmlId}.add(" . $_row->toJson() . ");\n";
}
?>
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

**System.xml**

```
<group id="groupslide" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Slider</label>
    <field id="small_image" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
        <label>Small Image</label>
        <validate>required-entry</validate>   
        <frontend_model>Vendor\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config</frontend_model>
        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>  

        <comment>Image size should be in Bytes(1 KB = 1024 Bytes, 10 KB = 10240 Bytes, 50 KB = 51200 Bytes, 100 KB = 102400 Bytes, 150 KB = 153600 Bytes)</comment>
    </field>
    <field id="medium_image" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
        <label>Medium Image</label>
        <validate>required-entry</validate>      
        <frontend_model>Vendor\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config</frontend_model>
        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>   

        <comment>Image size should be in Bytes(1 KB = 1024 Bytes, 10 KB = 10240 Bytes, 50 KB = 51200 Bytes, 100 KB = 102400 Bytes, 150 KB = 153600 Bytes)</comment>
    </field>
    <field id="large_image" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
        <label>Large Image</label>
        <validate>required-entry</validate>  
        <frontend_model>Vendor\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config</frontend_model>
        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>    

        <comment>Image size should be in Bytes(1 KB = 1024 Bytes, 10 KB = 10240 Bytes, 50 KB = 51200 Bytes, 100 KB = 102400 Bytes, 150 KB = 153600 Bytes)</comment>
    </field>
    <field id="extra_large_image" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
        <label>Extra Large Image</label>
        <validate>required-entry</validate>  
        <frontend_model>Vendor\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config</frontend_model>
        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model> 

        <comment>Image size should be in Bytes(1 KB = 1024 Bytes, 10 KB = 10240 Bytes, 50 KB = 51200 Bytes, 100 KB = 102400 Bytes, 150 KB = 153600 Bytes)</comment>
    </field>
    <field id="image_file_types" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
        <label>Image File Types</label>
        <validate>required-entry</validate>    
        <comment>Multiple values are seperated with comma</comment>
    </field>
</group>
<!--Slider configurations end--> 
<!--Banner configurations start--> 
<group id="groupbanner" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Banner</label>
    <field id="banner_small_image" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
        <label>Small Image</label>
        <validate>required-entry</validate>   
        <frontend_model>Vendor\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config</frontend_model>
        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>  

        <comment>Image size should be in Bytes(1 KB = 1024 Bytes, 10 KB = 10240 Bytes, 50 KB = 51200 Bytes, 100 KB = 102400 Bytes, 150 KB = 153600 Bytes)</comment>
    </field>
    <field id="banner_medium_image" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
        <label>Medium Image</label>
        <validate>required-entry</validate>      
        <frontend_model>Vendor\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config</frontend_model>
        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>   

        <comment>Image size should be in Bytes(1 KB = 1024 Bytes, 10 KB = 10240 Bytes, 50 KB = 51200 Bytes, 100 KB = 102400 Bytes, 150 KB = 153600 Bytes)</comment>
    </field>
</group>
```

Frontend model(Config.php)

```
class Config extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
       $this->setTemplate('vendor_namespace::mytemplate.phtml');

    }

    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        // Override in descendants to add columns, change add button label etc

        $this->addColumn('width', array(
            'label' => 'width',
            'style' => 'width:100px',
            'class' => 'validate-number validate-digits validate-greater-than-zero'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('height', array(
            'label' => 'height',
            'style' => 'width:100px',
            'class' => 'validate-number validate-digits validate-greater-than-zero'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('imagesize', array(
            'label' => 'image size',
            'style' => 'width:100px',
            'class' => 'validate-number validate-digits validate-greater-than-zero'
        ));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your  related code

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: @Piyush The template is working good for group 1, After I have added group 2 with same fields, but it is failed to generate unique id for each row in group 2

Comment: can you tell what unique id it is generating for any one field?

Comment: {"_1518413443029_29":{"width":"","height":"","imagesize":""}} like this, It was saved in core config table for single field

Comment: Same error here '<tr id="<%- _id %>">' _id get null in template